# Is Python's setup.py beneficial for internal applications?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, setup.py

I'm in the midst of writing our build/deployment scripts for a small Python application that will be run multiple times per day using a scheduled task. I figure now is as good a time as ever to investigate Python's `setup.py` feature.

My question is, is there any sort of benefit to investing the time in creating a `setup.py` file for internal business applications as opposed to say, writing a simple script that will activate my virtualenv, then download my pip packages based on my requirements file?

Comment: On second thought, I'm not sure I fully understand your question. You do not need to "activate" a `virtualenv` in order to install things to it or run scripts. Simply use the binaries located in `ENV/bin` (such as `ENV/bin/pip` or `ENV/bin/python`)

Comment: For deploying applications you don't need `setup.py`. So indeed you only need to create a virtualenv, install the files and schedule it to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setup.py` is intended for people who are writing their own Python code and need to deploy it.  If you either haven't written any Python code, or for some reason do not need to deploy any of the code you have written (you're not doing development in production, are you?), `setup.py` is not going to be terribly useful.